# How to test is method called on an object which is create inside other class?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

I'm working with laravel 5.5. And I need to test whether some method was called on an object (created inside other class) or not. How could I do it?

Example:

```
class A {
    public static function createQuery($variable){
        $b = new B($variable);
        if($variable === 1){
            $b->withShoes();
        }
        if($variable === 2){
            $b->withSocks();
        }
        if($variable === 1 || $variable === 3){
            $b->withFriends();
        }
        return $b->get();
    }
}

class B {
    public function withShoes(){
        ...
    }
    public function withSocks(){
        ...
    }
    public function withFriends(){
        ...
    }
    public function get(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like do make some test like this: was method `withShoes()` called when I called `A::createQuery($variable)`? Thanks for any help.